# How to select <a> tag HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, parsing

here is a screenshot of the  I am trying to select, I copied the Xpath from console, but when I run the program, it states that it is null:[Anchor tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaGXl.png).

I have tried copying the Xpath to the  tag as well as the  tag above it, and they both return a null value, but when I run the query in a browser and inspect the page, they both have a value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace AccessID2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    #region UI Event Handlers
    private void cmdGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RestClient rClient = new RestClient();
        rClient.endPoint = txtUrl.Text;

        debugOutput("Searching for Product");

        string strResponse = string.Empty;

        strResponse = rClient.makeRequest();
        debugOutput(strResponse);

        var html = strResponse;

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='anch_114']");

        txtID.Text = htmlNodes.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    private void debugOutput(string strDebugText)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(strDebugText + Environment.NewLine);
            txtResponse.Text = txtResponse.Text + strDebugText + Environment.NewLine;
            txtResponse.SelectionStart = txtResponse.TextLength;
            txtResponse.ScrollToCaret();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(ex.Message, ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }

   

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just select the anchor element:

```
var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='anch_114']");
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, it's still giving a null

Comment: hmm, does this line of code returns the anchor you need?
`var anchors = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").ToList();`

Comment: I tried it like this, It still says null.  Is this how to use it?

 var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

            var idNumber = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@id='anch_114']");
            var anchors = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a").ToList();

            if (idNumber == null)
            {
                txtID.Text = "Null Field";
            }
            else
            {
                txtID.Text = anchors.ToString();
            }

Comment: code looks ok, but `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants` is just another way to look for certain elements. It returns a list with anchor elements.
If that also returns null, maybe something is wrong with the loaded html.

Comment: Now I copied the HTML into a file, and set a path as a variable to read it from the file, and it's still giving null.  I think you are correct, but I'm not sure how to get it to read it.